# Failing test that record saves to pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, testing, eloquent, phpunit

I have a Board model and a Pin model, and they are many to many.  I am testing to make sure that when a pin gets created and assigned a board, it saves to the pivot table. I am having trouble figuring this out since I am new to testing.

Here is my Test:

```
/** @test */
public function a_pin_can_belong_to_a_board()
{
    $board = create('App\Board');
    $pin = make('App\Pin');

    $response = $this->post('/pins/create', $pin->toArray());

    $pin->boards()->sync($board);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('board_pin', [
        'board_id' => $board->id,
        'pin_id' => $pin->id
    ]);
}
```

Here is my Error:

```
1) Tests\Unit\PinTest::a_pin_can_belong_to_a_board
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity 
constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: board_pin.pin_id 
(SQL: insert into "board_pin" ("board_id", "pin_id") values (1, ))

Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT 
NULL constraint failed: board_pin.pin_id
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:200',
        'link' => 'required|max:255'
    ]);

    $pin = new Pin();

    $pin->title = $request->title;
    $pin->link = $request->link;
    $pin->user_id = auth()->id();

    $pin->save();

    $pin->boards()->sync($request->boards);

    return redirect("/pins/{$pin->id}");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is the pin getting saved? You can tell from that SQL output that the values array only has one for board_id. The values (1, )) part.

Comment: Well im somewhat new to testing, how would i tell? Wouldn't it be getting saved when it gets posted to that route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer! Instead of just using the make method on the pin instance, I used the create method and persisted it to the database, then just removed the post action. See below:

```
/** @test */
public function a_pin_can_belong_to_a_board()
{
    $board = create('App\Board');
    $pin = create('App\Pin');

    $pin->boards()->sync($board);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('board_pin', [
        'board_id' => $board->id,
        'pin_id' => $pin->id
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be careful about using `sync`. I would advise against using it and instead opt for `attach`. The reason being the following:

> You may also use the sync method to construct many-to-many
>   associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the
>   intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be
>   removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is
>   complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the
>   intermediate table

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) see "Syncing associations".

```
$pin->boards()->attach([$board->id])
```

Alternatively, although I'm not sure why you would choose this route you can use `syncWithoutDetaching` which does what one would expect:

> If you do not want to detach existing IDs, you may use the
>   syncWithoutDetaching method

The main issue seems to be that you are using `make` on your `pin` but then you do not save it. You are creating an instance by also posting to that endpoint but it is not the same as the instance you have created locally. In your case `$pin` does not have an ID because it was never saved. There is a separate `pin` that was created with the same attributes when you did the following:

`$this->post('/pins/create', $pin->toArray());`

If your response contains the pin's id, you could do something like follows:

```
$pin_id = $response->getContent()->id;
$pin = Pin::find($pin_id);
$pin->boards()->attach([$board->id]);
```